# Calculate text width server side with nodes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I would like to know how to calculate the *width* of a text string on the server side using node.js.

My initial approach was to use jQuery on the server side to create a virtual `<span>` element, populate the text, and call `width()` on that jQuery object.

Here is what I tried:

**server side code**

```
var $ = require('jquery')(require("jsdom").jsdom().parentWindow);

function calcWidth(text) {
  var span = $('<span />').html(text);
  return span.width();
}
```

But the above code always returns 0, no matter what the `text` is.

I have a good reason to do this on the server side; I am rendering an svg to the client and I need to know the *width* of the text while generating the svg.

Why is this not working, and do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You cannot get the _dimension_ of the element unless it is in **DOM**

Comment: I found a solution. I am using node-canvas to create a canvas and using the native `measureText()` HTML canvas API. Any better suggestions?